# Changing virtual page premissions

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver

I am trying to override the kill command In my module by replacing the pointer stored in sys_call_table, to a pointer to function i implemented.
I used the `kallsyms_lookup_name()` syscall to get the address of the table, and `lookup_address()` to get the address of the page.
now, my problem is the kernel protecting the page with r/w flag.
So, given a virtual page address, is there a way to modify the r/w flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need this?

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.3/source/arch/arm/mm/pageattr.c#L68\

At least, you can change your memory attribute for kernel module. Also, you can change your kernel text memory attribute as well.

As far as I tested, if we try to write ro memory in the kernel module, MMU will generate exception and you will see "invalid virtual memory" access.

You have to pass virtual memory address.

Comment: Im trying to avoid writing to a r/o page by changing the page premission to RW. In kernel mode, I belive i have the option to change the premission. I also tried to manipulate the bits with logical and\or directly but the linux will crash.

Comment: This is changing the kernel page permission. You can set ro or rw. You can give starting address of the page and number of the pages.